# Developing WPF .NET 3.5 application for Win7 and Win 8 OS

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, windows-8

I am developing WPF .NET application for Win7 and Win8 OS.

For now I am using .NET 3.5 platform, as I understood Win7 comes with .Net 3.5 integrated while Win8 comes with .Net4.

I want that the user will have the fastest installation with minimum pre-installations. What is the best way to do it? does the user with Win8 have to install .NET 3.5?

Comment: are you sure? as i understand .NET 4 does not include .NET 3.5

Comment: If you developed the app in .NET 3.5 then you don't need to worry about the user installing .NET on their system since Windows has .NET Framework installed (especially the ones which your app needs from Win7).

Answer (score 1):

Using 3.5 would make it work in Win7, but if the users don't have Internet or a DVD they can't install .net 3.5 in Windows 8. Because you can't include .Net 3.5 files in your setup you run into the isse that Win8 users can't use your tool.

Instead, you should use .Net 4.5.2 which also works in Windows 7. With .net 4.5.x you can add the [redistributable offline Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=397706) to the Setup of your application so that it will work fine on Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: thanks, if i rebuild the solution in .NET4 and it run it meens that it would run in Win8? also if i will work with 4.5.1 it will work with both Win7 and Win8 for sure?

Comment: Win 8 comes with .net 4.5, but you should use 4.5.2, because this is the newest version and replaces all 4.x versions.

Comment: i have 4.5.1 in my visual studio. is 4.5.2 will run on Win7 for sure with no pre-installation?

Comment: what is the best thing to do?

Comment: install this developer version to get the 4.5.2 projects: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637 and include the full installer in your setup: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand two things: 1. if i am developing in 4.5.2 the application will run on Win7 with no need to install .net 4.5.2 on user pc? 2.if i am developing in .net 3.5 how can i check if it will run on Win8 with no need to install 3.5 on Win8 pc?

Comment: if you develop for 4.5.2 all systems need 4.5.2. Simply add the .net 4.5.2 install to your setup to make sure it runs on both systems.

Comment: if the .net3.5 application have all components also in .net 4 to will it run on Win8 for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Win8 doesn't include .Net 3.5 automatically, so if a application require specific 3.5 version you have install 3.5 or unable it from control panel. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is example how you can do this.

Comment: thanks , but what is the best way to develop WPF application for both Win7 and Win 8 with no .NET as prerequisite?

Comment: No way. WPF requires .NET. And caring about 3.5 at this point is - bordering irresponsibility.

Comment: that meens that the application will not run on Win8 if the .NET 3.5 will not be enabled?

Comment: If application develop under the 3.5, it should work on win8 as well, but as Win8 include .net 4.0 so you application use any .net 3.5 specific thing which is not available in 4.0 then there will be problem. in that case you have install 3.5 explicity

Comment: how can i check if all my application code parts are included in .NET 4 too?

Comment: You can use to check the compatibility http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

Comment: is it recommended to develop in .net 3.5 or 4 for Win7 and Win8?