# Use Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) Secript in InstallShield to enable .net 3.5 windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, .net-3.5, installshield

I am using InstallShield for deploying my C# Application.

I want to enable .net 3.5 in windows 8.

I found on MSDN, for enable .net 3.5 in windows 8 using DISM script.

Can anyone give some suggestion to enable that feature at application installation time?

Comment: Q: Don't  Windows 8 PCs already have .Net installed (specifically, Net 4.5 or higher)?  Shouldn't that suffice for your .Net 3.5 app?

Comment: you are right my friend, but that feature is not activated in windows 8, we have to activate that refer this [http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/07/how-to-install-dotnet-framework-in-win8.html]

Comment: You should upgrade your solution to 4.5.2 and add the 4.5.2 redist to the setup http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107045/1466046

Answer (score 0):

The "Suite / Advanced UI" project type in InstallShield includes the in-the-box capability to install Windows roles and features, like .Net 3.5, IIS, and PowerShell.  "Suite / Advanced UI" projects can be used as a bootstrapper to wrap around your installation, providing more a more custom installation UI, bundle dependencies, run PowerShell scripts, sideload Windows Store applications, execute C# actions, and more...